# Отправка ajax запросов по ссылкам в массиве, как добавить последовательность?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Уже целый вечер не могу решить проблему..

Ссылки получаю так.

```
var links = response.responseJSON.links;
                        for (var key in links) {
                            var link = links[key];
// запускаем ajax добавления продукта
                            AddProduct(link);
                        }




 function AddProduct(link) {
            $.ajax({
                url:     'https://stroycentr82.ru/parsing/?section=parse_product',
                method: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: ({ url: link })

            });
```

Функция добавления продуктов по ссылке... Как сделать, что бы пока не получен статус 200 по настоящему запросу, следующий ajax не начинался.. что бы сервер не грузить и не вызывать подозрений у сайта, с которого заполняю продукцию..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AddProduct(response.responseJSON.links); // assume links is array
function AddProduct(links) {
  if (links.length) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://stroycentr82.ru/parsing/?section=parse_product',
      method: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { url: links.shift() },
      success: function() {
        AddProduct(links);
      },
      error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log("ERROR:", a, b, c);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: не работает почемуто, итерация выпооняется один раз

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение, работает исправно!